# Weighted Graph Path Traversal Question

Tags: graphs

You are given a graph of all the nodes and links between them. Each node has an associate value with it and each link contains the distance between the two nodes. Once you reach a node, your current value adds upon the value at the node. Once you collect the value at a node it is set to 0. Assuming you start at Node A and you must finish at Node B and you have a maximum distance you can travel, how do you find the optimal path to get from Node A to Node B while obtaining the highest value score?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Have you tried proving that your problem is hard?

Comment: I haven’t implemented any methods yet because all the ones I’ve thought of are slow. I was planning on finding everything possible path to get from A to B but this would probably be the slowest option. Are there any Wikipedia pages or other resources you could directly me to learn more about this?

Comment: I'm not asking about implementation; I'm asking about your attempts to come up with algorithms or prove them hard.  If everything you can think of seems slow, perhaps you should try to prove that the problem is hard.  What techniques do you know for doing that?  Are you familiar with NP-completeness and how to prove that a problem is NP-complete or NP-hard?  Can you tell us more about the context where you encountered this problem?  If it's from a course or textbook, that might give you more guidance to help you narrow down what approaches might be fruitful to investigate.